# Простой роутер через window.location.hash, помогите, пожалуйста!

Tags: javascript, html, css, router, spa

Пытаюсь написать простой роутер на чистом JS, работает он по такому принципу -

```js
const router = {
      getURL() {
       return window.location.hash.slice(1)
     },

     navigate(hash) {
       window.location.hash = hash
     }
    }

    const routes = [
      { path: "", component: "<h1>home</h1>"},
      { path: "about", component: "<h1>about</h1>" }
    ]

    function renderRoute() {

      let url = router.getURL()

     let route = routes.find(r => r.path === url)

     document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = route.component

    }

    function initRoutes() {
     window.addEventListener("hashchange", renderRoute())
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>

   <a href="#">Home</a>
   <a href="#about">About</a>

   <div id="app"></div>
 
  </body>
  </html>
```

И если изменить адрес на "#about" и перезагрузить страницу, то все будет хорошо и зарендерится содержимое route.component, которое относится к "about", но мне нужно реализовать это без перезагрузки страницы.(

P.S. Код скорее всего очень корявый, я писал его торопясь, да и я всего лишь новичок, так что не судите строго, заранее спасибо!

Comment: @Grundy тут правку интересную предлагают

Comment: @andreymal, ага :-) интересно, автор хотя бы попробовал решение из дубликата?:)